# Autostart application after copied the file

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using C# 4.5 and SQL Server 2014. I wrote a console application which takes 3 file names and folder which is defined in the `app.config` file and validates the data and imports the data in SQL Server.

I have given FTP portal to the client, they upload the data and informed me then manually I am running my exe file then data is importing. But I want an automatic process like once the client uploads 3 files in folder my console application auto start.

I thought of using `FileSystemWatcher`, but here problem is that if put file watcher to folder, create file event, I am getting event when the file is created, this will not work because I need the event when 3 files copied successfully.

This is my `app.config` file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SourceFolder" value="E:\UploadData" />
    <add key="ArchiveFolder" value="E:\UploadData\Archive" />
    <add key="LogFile" value="E:\UploadData\LogFile" />

    <add key="DisbursementFile" value="xxx_DISB.csv" /> 
    <add key="EmployeeFile" value="xxx_EMP.csv" />
    <add key="AmountFile" value="xxx_AMT.csv" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: can't you simply poll every X seconds? (FSW is not reliable actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Task Scheduler - task and schedule it to run with every 10 minutes of interval or as you like.

Comment: The file is so big like 2, 3 GB size, how to verify file copied successfully then the process will start?

Comment: create a service to maintain the flag in SQL table to check all files are copied, ask the client to update the flag using your service after completion of file copied. in your console application before process the file check the flag and then do your part.